# 3 set venn diagram with venneuler

Tags: r, venn-diagram

This is my code to create a 3-set venn diagram with the R package venneuler, inserting two rows of data in each circle and intersection (representing up and down regulated genes). I share it with you because it took me a while to find this solution.

```
library(venneuler)
MyVenn <- venneuler(c(A=2,B=2,C=2,"A&B"=0.8,"A&C"=0.7,"B&C"=0.8,"A&B&C"=0))
MyVenn$labels <- c("","","")
MyVenn$diameters<-c(0.4,0.4,0.4)
plot(MyVenn, col="grey80", border = "black")
          text(0.35,0.6,"181\n161", cex = 1.5) #A
          text(0.65,0.6,"27\n14", cex = 1.5) #B
          text(0.4997455,0.325,"0\n0", cex = 1.5) #C
          text(0.5,0.6,"0\n0", cex = 1.5) #AB,
          text(0.59,0.45,"0\n0", cex = 1.5)  #BC
          text(0.4,0.45,"0\n0", cex = 1.5)  #AC
          text(0.5,0.5,"0\n0", cex = 1.5) #ABC
```

And this is how it looks like (it is saved as 500x500):
[image]

I don't know though how to add labels outside the circles, suggestions, corrections, improvements are welcome

Comment: why don't you add labels with `text`?

Comment: Collection of all 2set and 3set venn diagrams: https://github.com/Ace-Cassidy/Venn-Diagram-Pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them manually as you did before, with `text()`:

```
text(MyVenn$centers[1, 1] + 0.2, MyVenn$centers[1, 2] + 0.2, "B", cex = 2)
text(MyVenn$centers[2, 1] + 0.2, MyVenn$centers[2, 2] - 0.2, "C", cex = 2)
text(MyVenn$centers[3, 1] - 0.2, MyVenn$centers[3, 2] + 0.2, "A", cex = 2)
```

[image: Imgur]